# Deserialization contracts for properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize jsons to a type that contains a property of interface type - IExceptionModel. I prescribe maps for interfaces to classes like this:

```
public static class JsonSerialization
{
    public static T FromJson<T>(this string obj) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(obj, Settings);
    
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new ContractResolver()
    };

    private class ContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var result = base.CreateContract(objectType);
            if (objectType == typeof(IExceptionModel))
            {
                    result.CreatedType = typeof(ExceptionModel);
                    result.DefaultCreator = () => result.CreatedType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(null);
            }
                
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my interface and class types:

```
public interface IExceptionModel : IModelBase
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

}
public class ExceptionModel : IExceptionModel
{
    public string Message { get ; set ; }
    public byte Index { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the class to deserialize to:

```
public class Status
{
    public IExceptionModel Error { get; set; }
}
```

When I take a proper input string like:

```
{
    "Error" : {
          "Message": "Error",
          "Index": 404
     }
}
```

and feed it to FromJson<Status> method, described above, I get Error property set to null, although I believe I have resolved the contract for the interface.
What else do I need to do in order to make it work?

---

Update.
When preparing this example, I messed some details. The IExceptionModel Error property doesn't have setter on the interface. It does on implementation. So now, when I have added setter to the interface, the property ends up with the needed value. If I wipe it, it has null after deserialization.

So the question turns into, how do I tell Newtonsoft Serializer to use the constructor of the implementation, use ITS getters and setters to fill what properties it can and only then treat it as the interface instance?

I found a workaround to assign an internal setter to the interface property and then instruct:

```
jsonContract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = true;
```

But it makes the interface look crooked, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

I made some corrections and this worked for me:

`result.CreatedType = typeof(Status);` --> `result.CreatedType = typeof(ExceptionModel);`

`public byte Index { get; set; }` --> `public int Index { get; set; }`

I uploaded this online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ETSJee

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;


public interface IModelBase {}
    
public interface IExceptionModel : IModelBase
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }

    }
    public class ExceptionModel : IExceptionModel
    {
        public string Message { get ; set ; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        public IExceptionModel Error { get; set; }
    }

public static class JsonSerialization
{
    public static T FromJson<T>(this string obj) 
    { 
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(obj, Settings);
    }

    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new ContractResolver()
    };

    private class ContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var result = base.CreateContract(objectType);
            if (objectType == typeof(IExceptionModel))
            {
                result.CreatedType = typeof(ExceptionModel);
                result.DefaultCreator = () => result.CreatedType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(null);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var txt = @"
        {
            'Error' : {
                'Message': 'Error',
                'Index': 404
            }
        }
        ";
        var obj = JsonSerialization.FromJson<Status>(txt);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Error.Index);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for  me without any contract resolvers

```
var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(txt);

public class Status
{
    public IExceptionModel Error { get; set; }
    
   [JsonConstructor]
    public Status (ExceptionModel error) {
        Error=error;
    }
    public Status() {}
}
```

if you need to use it in many classes you can use this code instead

```
public class Status
{
    [JsonProperty("Error")]
    private ExceptionModel _error
    {
        set { Error = value; }
        get { return (ExceptionModel)Error; }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IExceptionModel Error { get; set; }
}
```

test

```
    var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(txt);
    Console.WriteLine(status.Error.Index); //404
    Console.WriteLine(status.Error.Message); //Error

public class MyClass:Status
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems even witty, but would make me write up the json constructors to the hell of my other models. I wish I wouldn't have to.

Comment: @IgorZhurbenko I updated my answer